# Connecting to an On-prem Database from within Snowflake

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, cloud, etl

Can a connection to an on-prem database (e.g. Sybase) be made directly from Snowflake, or does it need to be made external to Snowflake? E.g., I know I can make a connection to my DB in some AWS compute (EMR, Lambda, EC2) and then load that data into Snowflake by opening a connection to Snwoflake, but I'm not sure I can open the connection from within a Python script that runs in Snowflake itself (a Python stored procedure).

I know that 3rd party tools like Talend, Informatica, and Fivetran are often used for this, but I want to know if I can just use Python in Snowflake.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use External Access Integration to access a database other than Snowflake.

See [Ingest External Data into Snowflake with Snowpark and JDBC](https://medium.com/@orellabac/ingest-external-data-into-snowflake-with-snowpark-and-jdbc-eb487b61078c) for an example.

From the article

> 1. Create a network rule
> 2. Create an external access integration
> 3. For this use case a Java Tabular function will be very useful.This function will just leverage very standard JDBC apis, the steps are:
>
>    - Load the JDBC driver
>    - Load the JDBC driver
>    - Create a JDBC connection
>    - Create an statement
>    - Execute the query
>    - Get the metadata
>    - Retrieve and return the results